# Demonstrate colinearity of two vectors in math exercise

Tags: vectors

I'm getting stuck with a part of my math exercise where I have to demonstrate the colinearity of two vectors without using the coordinates.

Note: All the vectors I will show will not have their arrow on top of them because I don't know how to do it in stack exchange.

MN = AC + 1/2 AB

MP = 4/3 AC + 2/3 AB

How to prove that vector MN and vector MP are colinear?

I heard about proving the colinearity with using factors but how can I use it in this exercise?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\begin{matrix}1&1/2\\4/3&2/3\end{matrix}\right|=1\cdot\frac23-\frac12\cdot\frac43=0$$

Also:

$$\frac43\overrightarrow{MN}-\overrightarrow{MP}=0$$

Comment: You can use the method x'y - xy' = 0 anyway for this exercise?I was thinking that it is obligated to know coordinates to use it.

Comment: I have not used coordinates since there is no basis involved. Nevertheless, you (that is, your teacher) may prefer the second proof.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thank you very much!